# Chromedriver navigating to mobile site instead of web version on centos

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am running headless chrome on centos, with

```
headless chrome version 2.38,
and google-chrome-stable version 67.0,
selenium 3.12
```

When trying to open a site using driver, it is not opening actual web version of site on centos, same works fine on macos.

Using below given chromeoptions:

```
"CHROME_OPTIONS" : [ 
        "--headless", 
        "----disable-gpu", 
        "--ignore-certificate-errors", 
        "window-size=1920,1080" ]
```

Couldn't understand why does it work this way

Comment: Why do you have 4 `-` in `----disable-gpu` ?

Comment: @BhagwatiMalav `not opening actual web version` ... what does it opens actually? What are you trying to validate?

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for responding.I am crawling data from some specific site.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "web version" you are implying that there is both a 'desktop' and a 'mobile' presentation for your web application. If this is the case, web applications typically have two different methods that they use to detect whether a client is a mobile or desktop browser:

1. The web server inspects the user agent to see if the browser is explicitly labelled as a mobile version
2. The web application front-end performs calculations based off of the DPI measurements of the window it is running within

The first method rarely occurs anymore and can easily be subverted. The second method would be easy to diagnose if the browser wasn't running in a headless mode. It may seem like the browser should load the desktop version at a resolution of 1920x1080, but that isn't how DPI works. DPI is a scaling factor that can vary between operating systems (which could explain why your setup works on macOS). To eliminate this potential issue, try adding `--force-device-scale-factor=1` to your `CHROME_OPTIONS` arguments and run the test again.